# Simulating no local storate in jasmine tests

Tags: jasmine

I have some javascript code that uses localstorage, but falls back to cookies. I'd like to test the cookie accessing part with saga code coverage. However, saga and jasmine support local storage. How can I run my unit tests without localstorage as a feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still on it, let me know if this works

```
Object.defineProperty(
    window,
    'localStorage',
    {
        value: null,
        configurable:false,
        writable: false,
        enumerable:false
    }
);
```